# Strange unpacking of a packed array with Insert

Tags: list-manipulation, packed-arrays

In Mathematica 11.1.1, when a packed array is stored within another list, it gets unexpectedly unpacked when `Insert`ing something into the outer list.

Create a packed array:

```
Needs["Developer`"];
On["Packing"];

packedlist = Range[100000];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[packedlist]

(* True *)
```

When nesting the packed array in another list, it remains packed:

```
outerlist = {1, 2, 3, packedlist};
Developer`PackedArrayQ[Last[outerlist]]

(* True *)
```

But then, when inserting an element into the `outerlist`, for some reason the `packedlist` is being unpacked:

```
Insert[outerlist, 4, 1];

(* During evaluation of In[391]:= FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to HoldForm. *)
(* During evaluation of In[391]:= FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {100000}. *)
```

Why does this happen? There is no unpacking with other operations, like:

```
Append[outerlist, 4];
Prepend[outerlist, 0];
Drop[outerlist, {1}];

(* No unpacking *)
```

Answer (score 6):

That's indeed weird. It still happens in version 11.3. I don't think that there is a "good" reason for this, because one can use `Join` (without unpacking) instead:

```
insert[list_, a_, k_] := Join[
  list[[1 ;; If[k < 0, Length[list] + k + 1, k - 1]]],
  {a},
  list[[If[k < 0, Length[list] + k + 2, k] ;;]]
  ]
```

By the way, I have made the experience that `Join` often works better than `Prepend` and `Append`. But I have no clue why.

Comment: Interesting... thank you for the `Join-based` `insert` implementation. I wonder if someone knows _why_ it happens...

Comment: Me too. You should also consider reporting it to the support.

Comment: The issue has been confirmed by the Wolfram Support. They said that this functionality has to be implemented for each of the functions (`Append`, `Join`, ...) and so far has not been done for `Insert`. Might happen in future versions.

Comment: Thanks @TheoTiger. for the feedback. Another step to a better software.

Comment: The problem doesn't occur anymore with V 13.3

Comment: Thank you, that is good to know! =)